# Commit failed (details follow): Can't open 'D:\Repositories\thing\db\svn-B4C5347A': The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error

Tags: svn, commit

I am getting this error when I trying to commit using Tortoise SVN.

I googled around but was unable to find this particular type of error message.

Any ideas?

By the way, I checked my freespace on my drives. One has 17gb left the other has 1tb of free space.

It's also worth pointing out that the "Directories" directory does not exist on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing relating to me, just a misconfiguration of the repo itself.